# Declaring a structure in a header file

Tags: c

I want to declare a structure in a header file. When I declare a simple variable in a header file I simply specify the variable as external like this.

The variable in the .c file:

```
int var;
```

And the same variable presented in the header file:

```
extern int var;
```

So far so good. But what about a struct? If I have the following struct in my .c file

```
typedef struct
{
   unsigned char seconds;
   unsigned char minutes;
   unsigned char hours;
   unsigned char day;
   unsigned char month;
   union
   { 
      unsigned int year; 
      unsigned char year_byte[2];
   }year_vars;
 }time;
```

How do I declare the structure in the header file?

Comment: what you want? `structure` or `structure variable`? both are seperate things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type definitions should go in the header only. They do not need to be repeated in the `.c` files. Simply include the header in your source files to access the type definitions.

#### time.h

```
typedef struct
{
  ...
} time;
```

#### time.c

```
#include "time.h"
```

Comment: As a side note, don't pick the same name for your header file as one of the standard libraries.

Comment: Why not? `#include <time.h>` versus `#include "time.h"` makes it easy to tell which is which.

Comment: The compiler is free to implement `<time.h>` versus `"time.h"` in pretty much any way it wants, it is impl.defined behavior. Further, the standard actually states that (6.10.2) if you use `" "` and the header can't be found, the following applies: _"The named source file is searched for in an implementation-defined manner. If this search is not supported, or if the search fails, the directive is reprocessed as if it read_ `# include <h-char-sequence> new-line`".

Comment: Even more important, 7.1.2 states : _"If a file with the same name as one of the above < and > delimited sequences, not provided as part of the implementation, is placed in any of the standard places that are searched for included source files, the behavior is undefined."_ So the code you posted with `#include "time.h"` is actually guaranteed to be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a global variable is not the same thing as declaring a type. If the typedef should be visible to everyone that includes your h file, then naturally the typedef needs to be in the h file.

And the other way around: if the typedef is local to your C file, there is no need to present it to the caller at all.

Please note that there is never a reason to use global non-constant variables in C. Replace them with static file scope variables in your C file, that are accessed through setter/getter functions.

Answer (score 1):

Into the .h go:

- Definitions of all types to be used for externally visible variables
- All `extern` declarations of variables (thus externally visible variables)

Into the .c go:

- Definitions of all types to be used by internal-only visible variables
- Definitions of all variables (visible externally and internally)